# Delete file in Get method web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an issue in my Web Api when I try to delete some files from the server, i get this error

> "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
>   another process"

My delete method is called in this get method :

```
public IQueryable<FriendChallenge> GetJudgedChallenge(string id)
        {
            var friendChallenges = challengeFriendRepo.GetFriendJudgeChallenge(id);
            var query = friendChallenges;

            ChangeFriendChallenge(friendChallenges, "");


            query.ForEach(fc => fc.Challenge = challengeRepo.Get(fc.ChallengeId));
            query.ForEach(fc => fc.Friend = friendRepo.Get(fc.FriendId));

            query.ForEach(fc => fc.Challenge.User.UserName = AESCrypt.DecryptRijndael(fc.Challenge.User.UserName, fc.Challenge.User.SecurityStamp));

            deleteFile(friendChallenges);

            return query.AsQueryable();
        }
```

To be sure that i can delete the file, I have to call delete method from this get method.

So my delete method loop in my list and i get the filename to create the path :

```
        string localFilePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\ChallengeContent\";
        localFilePath += imagePath;

        if (File.Exists(localFilePath))
        {
           // Content.Dispose();
            File.Delete(localFilePath);
        }
```

The file exist, but when the File.Delete is call i get the error...

All my Read method are done in a using, the write is a multipart method.

EDIT :

My write method :

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile()
        {

            // Check whether the POST operation is MultiPart?
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            string appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\ChallengeContent\";
            string fileName = String.Empty;
            if (Directory.Exists(appPath) == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);
            }

            CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(appPath);
            List<string> files = new List<string>();


            try
            {
                // Read all contents of multipart message into and save files in the server
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

                foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                {
                    files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName));
                }

                // Send OK Response along with saved file names to the client.
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, files);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
            }


        }
```

EDIT 2 :

Sorry I did not think to add it with in the previous edit

```
  public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// multipart provider
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">path</param>
        public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get local file name multipart
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="headers">http header</param>
        /// <returns>file name</returns>
        public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
        {
            return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where in your upload code you actually save files to disk?

Comment: The files are not getting saved

Comment: They are, if they were not why I'll post here

Comment: @Orcusz add a code where you save files.

Comment: I added it... the multiparse method do it, the files are saved with this method :                 await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

Comment: @OrcusZ what does ChangeFriendChallenge method do?

Comment: This method just do some business work, and update some data in my database. This method get some data, and update it before they were sent to the client. After the preparation of this data , I suppress the files if they exist to save data storage

Comment: Identify the process with the lock on the file using ProcessMonitor (it's probably your web app) then change code to release the lock asap &/or check if the file is locked before deleting it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11060322

Comment: If I was a consumer of this API I wouldn't expect it to delete something. GET methods shouldn't really delete things. Have a read of CQS principals https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation

Comment: Of course, but only for table things?